# Win32 IO Performance Problem

Tags: c, performance, winapi, file-io

Recently I ran into a "fun" problem with the Microsoft implementation of the CRTL. [`tmpfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x7sakw(VS.80).aspx) places temp files in the root directory and completely ignores the temp file directory. This has issues with users who do not have privileges to the root directory (say, on our cluster). Moreover, using [`_tempnam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs3e7355(VS.80).aspx) would require the application to remember to delete the temporary files, which it is unable to do without a considerable amount of rework.

Therefore I bit the bullet and wrote Win32 versions of all of the IO routines (create_temp, read, write, seek, flush) which call the appropriate method. One thing I've noticed is the now abysmal performance of the library.

Results from the test suite:

```
CRTL:    4:30.05 elapsed
Win32:  11:18.06 elapsed

Stats measured in my routines:
Writes:  3129934 (   44,642,745,008 bytes)
Reads:    935903 (    8,183,423,744 bytes)
Seeks:   2205757 (2,043,782,657,968 bytes traveled)
Flushes:   92442
```

Example of a CRTL v. Win32 method:

```
int io_write(FILE_POINTER fp, size_t words, const void *buffer)
{
#if !defined(USE_WIN32_IO)
    {
        size_t words_written = 0;

        /* read the data */
        words_written = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t), words, fp);
        if (words_written != words)
        {
            return errno;
        }
    }
#else /* !defined(USE_WIN32_IO) */
    {
        DWORD bytesWritten;

        if (!WriteFile(fp, buffer, words * sizeof(uint32_t), &bytesWritten, NULL)
            || (bytesWritten != words * sizeof(uint32_t)))
        {
            return GetLastError();
        }
    }
#endif /* USE_WIN32_IO */

    return E_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, they are effectively identical, yet the performance (in release mode) is wildly divergent. Time spent in `WriteFile` and `SetFilePointer` dwarf the time spent in `fwrite` and `fseeko`, which seems counterintuitive.

Ideas?

UPDATE: perfmon notes that `fflush` is about 10x cheaper than `FlushFileBuffers` and `fwrite` is ~1.1x slower than `WriteFile`. The net result is a huge performance loss with `FlushFileBuffers` used in the same manner as `fflush`. There is no change from `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` to `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS` either.

Comment: I'm sure you've heard the fable of the "Princess and the Pea", in which the princess is so delicate that she is made uncomfortable by the presence of a pea under her mattress. So she piles on matress after matress but is still uncomfortable. Programmers can be like that when they put "wrappers" around existing routines or classes, hoping to fix something that bothers them.

Comment: ... I think it's better just to get to the bottom of the issue and remove the pea or otherwise fix the problem.

Comment: I agree with you, but my group has neither the infinite time nor the infinite money which solve the actual problem. I've opted for the simplest change rather than add the Win32 IO support. This whole IO wrapper exists because the code still makes calls thinking it is running on a Honeyboxen. The above code is greatly simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's probably due to this issue, described on MSDN's page for [`FlushFileBuffers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Due to disk caching interactions
>   within the system, the
>   FlushFileBuffers function can be
>   inefficient when used after every
>   write to a disk drive device when many
>   writes are being performed separately.
>   If an application is performing
>   multiple writes to disk and also needs
>   to ensure critical data is written to
>   persistent media, the application
>   should use unbuffered I/O instead of
>   frequently calling FlushFileBuffers.
>   To open a file for unbuffered I/O,
>   call the CreateFile function with the
>   FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and
>   FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH flags. This
>   prevents the file contents from being
>   cached and flushes the metadata to
>   disk with each write. For more
>   information, see CreateFile.

In general, `FlushFileBuffers` is an "expensive" operation, [since it flushes everything in the write-back cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/ce_base/archive/2006/03/15/IncreaseFSThroughput.aspx):

> FlushFileBuffers(): This function will flush everything in the write-back cache, as it
>   does not know what part of the cache belongs to your file.  This can take a lot of time,
>   depending on the cache size and the speed of the media.  How necessary is it?  There is
>   a thread which goes through and writes out dirty pages, so it is likely not very
>   necessary.

I presume that [`fflush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz%28VS.71%29.aspx) does not flush the entire write-back cache.  In that case, it's much more efficient, but that efficiency comes at the risk of potential data loss.  The CRT's source code for `fflush` confirms this, since [`_commit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17618685%28VS.71%29.aspx) calls `FlushFileBuffers`:

```
/* lowio commit to ensure data is written to disk */
if (str->_flag & _IOCOMMIT) {
        return (_commit(_fileno(str)) ? EOF : 0);
}
```

From the implementation of `_commit`:

```
if ( !FlushFileBuffers((HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(filedes)) ) {
        retval = GetLastError();
}
```

Comment: FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING has pretty onerous requirements which cannot be easily met by this application, or in the time required for me to rewrite. I guess I am wondering how in the world the CRTL methods are able to do this efficiently but using the raw Win32 I am not...

Comment: Probably because they don't immediately commit your changes to disk in the default case.  If you always call `_commit` after `fflush` in your unit tests, are the times closer?

Comment: Yep, they're almost identical, what this means is the code i've inherited doesn't quite do what it says it does with the original CRTL code, so perhaps I can accept the performance decrease for now. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/66052

Comment: Right.  The Win32 version is taking the safest approach possible, while the CRT implementation is erring on the side of efficiency.  I guess it's up to you to decide which approach is appropriate in your particular situation...  :-)

Comment: The maddening part is less the performance change but the fact that none of the CRTL implementations match up with their *NIX counterparts making maintenance of this code a nightmare. If only I could adopt APR or something similar...

Comment: What with https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170510-00/?p=95505: in the Windows 7 time frame, EIDE and SATA drivers do not respect the FUA flag, which means that your writes may still be buffered by the drive's internal memory.
This means that even with the WRITE_THROUGH flag, EIDE and SATA drivers might still ignore the (FUA) flag and still keep data in RAM (lost if there's a power failure).
http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2008/04/disks-lies-and-damn-disks/ explains this better: FUA is dropped for performance reasons since SATA and EIDE can only process one command at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, the C runtime library functions buffer the data and only trigger the write operation (hence the need for functions like `fflush`). I don't think that `WriteFile` buffers the write operation so every time you call `WriteFile`, an I/O operation gets triggered whereas with `fwrite`, the I/O gets triggered when the buffer has reached a certain size.

As you can see from your measurements, the buffered I/O tends to be more efficient...

Comment: From my reading of `CreateFile` and its options, `WriteFile` should buffer its output. There are attributes that control if an IOP is generated for each call (like FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING or FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH).

Comment: I was finally able to get VS's profiler to run (it was generating 65G datasets which it couldn't analyze) and discovered that when using CRTL methods, `fflush` takes a fraction of the time `FlushFileBuffers` does, and `fwrite` takes a smidgen more than `WriteFile`. However, the difference in flush performance dwarfs the write performance.

Comment: I think Emerick's answer has a good handle on what the reason for that is. Is there a chance that you can just flush buffers rarely or not even at all? If you feel you have to flush buffers, maybe flush them just before you close the file?

Comment: I wish, unfortunately much of the behavior is out of my control.

Answer (score 2):

I might be crazy, but wouldn't it be easier to just write a replacement for `tmpfile` that uses `fopen(temporaryname, "wbTD+")`, where you generate your own `temporaryname`?

At least then you don't have to worry about reimplementing `<file.h>`.

Comment: I gather T is an extension mode?

Comment: I meant to say D. And for MSVC, yes; D means FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, T means FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY.

Comment: +1, but I'm going to keep Emerick's as the answer as he covers the question about performance. Since I'm tasked with changing the bare minimum, I'm going with your suggestion for the actual problem fix.

Comment: Yes, well, I was about to suggest reading the source for fread, fwrite, and fflush, but I figured that it would be more helpful to just suggest replacing tmpfile. You should read the source for them anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a little unclear on what the question is.  You start out by talking about managing the lifetime of a temporary file and then jump to wrapping an entire file i/o interface.  Are you asking about how to manage a temporary file without the performance penalty of wrapping all the file I/O?  Or are you interested in how the CRT functions can be faster than the WinAPI functions they are built on top of?

Several of the comparisons being made between the C run-time functions and the WinAPi functions are of the apples and oranges variety.

The C run-time functions buffer the I/O in library memory.  There is another layer of buffering (and caching) in the OS.

`fflush` flushes the data from the library buffers to the OS.  It may go directly to disk, or it may go to OS buffers for later writing.  `FlushFileBuffers` gets data from the OS buffers onto the disk, which generally takes longer than moving data from the library buffers to the OS buffers.

Unaligned writes are expensive.  The OS buffers make unaligned writes possible, but they don't really speed up the process.  The library buffers may accept several writes before pushing data to the OS, effectively reducing the number of unaligned writes to the disk.

It's also possible (though this is just a guess) that the library routines are taking advantage of overlapped (asynchronous) I/O to the disk, where your straight-to-WinAPI implementation is all synchronous.

Comment: The backstory was to handle questions of the nature "why not stick with CRTL".